# Visual studio 2019 error: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or neutral culture

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

ive been sitting with this problem for 2 days now in regards to visual studio.

When I create a service-based database and try opening it, I get an error stating the following:
Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer.SqlViewSupport.xml" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

I've searched online for it but couldn't find anything relating to my problem, was hoping someone here could help me?
I'm using a windows form app.net framework

I've tried reinstalling visual studio plenty of times with no luck

Comment: Just double checking, did you install both the *.NET Desktop* and the *Data storage and processing workloads* to your Visual Studio instance as documented as pre-requisites? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-sql-database-by-using-a-designer?view=vs-2019#prerequisites

Comment: yep, it seemed to be a recent problem with visual studio i found a fix here though https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate/1505966. thanks for replying :)

Answer (score 3):

i just found the solution  here
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate/1505966

i hope it helps   you have to download a .dll   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.sqlserver.dll from

i hope it helps  if not let me know ill try to help you